# How to bulk rename files in a folder using a timestamp?

Tags: batch

The timestamp layout should be YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.fileformat. I'd like to use the metadata info contained in each file, in particular the Last Edit timestamp info. I'm using Windows 10 so a solution using the command prompt is what I'm looking for. I tried using different scripts found online but they add unwanted characters and spaces

Comment: Actually a powershell script is what you should be using to do this. You'll need to do some research and testing. If you run in to a specific problem with code you can post it and ask questions about it. But we don't write scripts for you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to use PowerShell this is easy. I personally use it for automatically naming my Jekyll blog posts.

This is really simple:

```
(Get-ChildItem) | ForEach {Rename-Item  $_.FullName "$($_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")).extension" }
```

---

#### edit:

Since OP didn't change the placeholder (.extension), here's another script to rename those files. And don't forget to replace REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR EXTENSION with your extension (.exe, .txt, .png, .jpg)

```
$ext = "REPLACE THIS WITH YOUR EXTENSION" # e.g. exe, jpg, txt, etc.
Get-ChildItem | For-Each {Rename-Item $_.Name $_.Name.Replace(".extension", "$($ext)"}
```

---

## super important edit:

I probably should've written it this way in the first place, but here's one that keeps the extension:

```
(Get-ChildItem) | ForEach {Rename-Item  $_.FullName ($_.LastWriteTime.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + $_.Extension)}
```

Comment: isn't there a placeholder for file format? the timestamp is correct by it literally added .extension at the end

Comment: Now you need a new script. Don't rerun that one.

Comment: What extension do you want, @hiru?

Comment: well there are different files in the folder with gif png and jpg format. with batch scripts there are parameters you can use as placeholder to keep the input file format consistent with the output, does powershell have something like that? example http://www.robvanderwoude.com/parameters.php

Comment: Did you back up the files?

Comment: nope but I manually renamed all of them and found out what was the former file format using this tool https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32

I have other folders to rename so I'll probably make a backup now

Comment: Alright, I edited my post with a script that could've avoided that headache for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked really well! What happens if there are subfolders in a folder? With your very first sample the script renamed the folders too

Comment: Do you wish to rename the subfolders or no? And do you wish to rename the contents of the subfolders?

Comment: I'd like to rename only files leaving folders untouched